# React routing always loads the same component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to add routing to my simple application:

```
import Home from './componantes/Home'
import Contact from './componantes/Contact'
import Aboutus from './componantes/Aboutus'
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom'
const routing = (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Router path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Router path ="/about" component={Aboutus} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

but whatever url I try to access `/contact` or `/about` it always takes me to home component.

my aboutus componant:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Contact extends React.Component{
    render() {           
        return (
            <h1>Contact componant</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: add your home and aboute us code both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [exact](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool) prop to the `/` Route to tell that you only want it to match when the location matches exactly.

Also you have typos in router definition, instead of Router you need to use Route for contact and about us.

So these lines must be corrected:

```
<Router path="/contact" component={Contact} /> 
<Router path ="/about" component={Aboutus} />
```

```js
   <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path ="/about" component={Aboutus} />
      </div>
    </Router>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-curie-y51z1)

Answer (score 2):

For routes you can use Switch. Switch decide which router is called and second one is put your component in ordered way like home at the bottom.So , our app will check /contact and /about before / route.you can check more about react-router-dom on official doc.

```
import Home from './componantes/Home'
import Contact from './componantes/Contact'
import Aboutus from './componantes/Aboutus'
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router , Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
const App = (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path ="/about" component={Aboutus} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root')); //need to change
```

Comment: make sure you are using right link for <Link to='/contact' /> and for home <Link to='/' />

Comment: I have updated my code and added `Switch` to it but now when I am trying to access `/contact` it shows blank page and there is now error on console

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `exact` prop for your home route, so it will be triggered only when the url is `/`. Also `routing` has to be a valid react component and rendered accordingly:

```
const Routing = () =>  (
    <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Router path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Router path ="/about" component={Aboutus} />
    </Router>
  )

ReactDOM.render(<Routing/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Hi I tried same it work for path `/` but when I try to access `/contact` or `/about` it shows empty page. there is simple `h1` return in both the componates

Comment: The issue might also be with your `Contact` and `Aboutus` components.