# how to implement child routing in functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am new to React. I am facing an issue for adding child routes with functional components.

I got to know that for class components we use like

```
<Router>
    <Route component={Main}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/cars" component={Car}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
</Router>`
```

and to access in component we use `{this.props.children}`.

Can someone please let me know how to write syntax for child routes in functional components. (I used `react-router-dom`).

Comment: refer my answer which helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/59786344/11982418

Comment: <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>

Try `exact` prop

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i am able to navigate between routes.but main issue is  i need to have nested routing where i am not able to call details/projects using link tag. syntax  is  <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/project" component={Projects} />
          <Route path="details" component={Details} /> </Route>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you read [react-router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing) first.

A functional component sample could be as follows:

- Basic Route

**Routes.component.js**

```
import * as React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";

const Routes = props =>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Where **Router** is a *BrowserRouter that uses HTML5 history API to sync your UI with the URL*, **Switch** *renders the first child `<Route>` that matches the location by URL* and **Route** *is to render some UI when its path matches the current URL*.

- Nested Route

**Dashboard.component.js**

```
import * as React from "react";
import {Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Dashboard = ({ match }) =>
  <div>
    <h2>Dashboard</h2>

    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${match.url}/projects`}>Projects</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route path={`${match.path}/projects`} component={Projects} />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Within the component where you want to nest another route by entering it in *Route component* you acquire the *[match object](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)* in the props.

With this you can use its properties:

- `match.url`: which is the portion of url collected from the parent and build another `<Link>` child
- `match.path`: which is the path used to link and build another `<Route>` child

I'll tell you more about it [in this example I made](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-1cp3d).
You've to click on Dashboard

It's all in the React Router documentation :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i am able to navigate between routes.but main issue is  i need to have nested routing where i am not able to call details/projects using link tag. syntax  is  <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/project" component={Projects} />
          <Route path="details" component={Details} /> </Route>

Comment: I mean to say I want to have a routing like dashboard/details and dashboard/ projects like nested routing.in my requirements I will have many nested routing s like component d inside c , component c inside b, component b inside a.mutliple nested routing based on conditions.thanks in advance

Comment: Finally, with my revision I think I've understood what you want and it works, you can try it out with the link below :) @MounikaKommuri

Comment: thanks for the solution.it helped me in finding out the issue .i am using okta react login.so with this when i tried to add nested route i got the error like  i am getting Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://projects/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:3000' and URL 'http://localhost:3000/'.